# How can I add WS-A adressing to a SOAP webservice-request via Robot Framework?

Tags: soap, robotframework

I am new with Robot Framework and I run into a problem.

I try to call a web service that requires WSA (Web Service Addressing).

I tried sending a request while using SoapUI.
Sending a request via SoapUI provides a `<wsa:Action>`, a `<wsa:RelatesTo>` and a `<wsa:MessageID>` tag in the header when WSA is enabled.

Now I want to do the same with RobotFramework.

How can I inject these same tags via Robot Framework?

Here is my test

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SudsLibrary
Library           Collections
Library           String

*** Test Cases ***
test
    [Tags]    blah
    Create Soap Client    C:${/}Robot WS${/}WS${/}wsdl${/}C60W30A.wsdl
    Set Http Authentication    MyUID    MyPWD
    ${C60W30A}=    Create Wsdl Object    ns0:Invoer
    ${taimen}=    Set Soap Headers    "wsa:Action"     GenBetKenmOperation
    Set Wsdl Object Attribute    ${C60W30A}    Functie    04
    Set Wsdl Object Attribute    ${C60W30A}    Bronsysteem    COA
    Set Wsdl Object Attribute    ${C60W30A}    Gebruiker    WILLT10
    ${result}=    Call Soap Method    GenBetKenmOperation    ${C60W30A}
```

Where the resulting XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.MyCompany.nl/inning/coa/GenererenBetKenmerk" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns0:Body>
      <ns1:GenererenBetKenm>
         <Invoer>
            <Functie>04</Functie>
            <Bronsysteem>COA</Bronsysteem>
            <Gebruiker>GeBrID</Gebruiker>
         </Invoer>
      </ns1:GenererenBetKenm>
   </ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And the error:

```
FAIL : WebFault: Server raised fault: 'A required header representing a Message Addressing Property is not present'
```

As you can see the `<wsa:Action>` tag is missing. As wel are the other SOAP-header tags when I add them.

Comment: Welcome to [so] where we aim to try and help you with your programming difficulties. Often this starts with showing us the code you're working on and explaining what you expect it to do and what you observe it actually does. In case you've tried several things already, mentioning those will eliminate obvious questions or comments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added the requested code. I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.